# json.net on windows ce (dotnet 2)

Tags: json, windows-ce, json.net, deserialization

I'm having a problem with deserializing a json string to a dictionary. I'm using the json version for dotnet 2.0, on windows CE 6. I use this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(str);
```

This code runs perfectly on windows xp and 7, but it is giving me problems on windows CE. I also get a warning "Warning 2 Reference to type 'System.DateTimeOffset' claims it is defined in 'v2.0\WindowsCE\mscorlib.dll', but it could not be found Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

Does anyone know how to get it working under windows CE .net 2? Or has a different solution?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a json.net version that worked for me:

http://jsoncf.codeplex.com/

Comment: how did you add this to reference ? i have copied the file to Desktop folder and referenced from there. But it shows emulator has no sufficient space for deployment.